# Error "Duplicate method EnquiryForm() in type EnquiryForm" for @AllArgsConstructor and @NoArgsConstructor

Tags: spring-annotations

```
  package cpc.ajinkyaproject.model; 

    @Setter
    @getter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor  
    public class EnquiryForm
    {

        }
```

This is the code I have, and I am getting an error. The @AllArgsConstructor and @NoArgsConstructor gives error:

> "Duplicate method EnquiryForm() in type EnquiryForm".

Comment: Is that the full code? I notice you typed `@getter` with a lowercase `g`. It should be `@Getter`, however, that won't be solving the issue you describe. You are actually using `@AllArgsConstructor` as well, on a class that does not have any properties.

Comment: I think it is because `AllArgsConstructor` and `NoArgsConstructor` both are making constructor `EnquiryForm()`. Since you have no variable inside the class. Both of the annotation are making same constructor.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you haven't declared any variables in the class. So default constructor and parameterized constructor work/deliver same functionality by JVM.
So declare any variables first and see the difference.